# Set class on page load for filterable grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a wordpress site I am using a filterable grid that shows 2 categories with a sandbox effect. The default functionality is to show all categories with no way to display a defined category on page load.

Until the menu item is clicked the class is empty. When then category menu item is clicked the class becomes "selected" like this :

```
<a data-option-value=".cat3" class="selected" href="#"><span>Portfolio 1</span><span class="num">10</span></a>
```

So, I tried to enable this on page load using jquery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#filter-by li:first a").addClass("selected");
});
```

When the page loads, the tab is now selected, but the grid still displays all of the items from both categories. The desired outcome would be to only show the items from the category that is selected.

Here is the code from the filterable grid on page load which displays all items (both categories).

```
<ul data-option-key="filter" class="option-set clearfix" id="filter-by"><li><a data-option-value=".cat3" class="" href="#"><span>Portfolio 1</span><span class="num">10</span></a></li><li><a data-option-value=".cat4" class="" href="#"><span>Portfolio 2</span><span class="num">10</span></a></li></ul>
```

How can I make it so that each time the page loads, Portfolio 1 is the default category shown?

Comment: check my edit regarding your last comment

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering the click event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#filter-by li:first a").addClass("selected").click();
});
```

when you wrote:

*Until the menu item is clicked the class is empty. When then category menu item is clicked the class becomes "selected"*

I assume this also triggers a function on click, not just adding the class

**EDIT**

if you need to query for the `<a>` tag using an attribute like `data-option-value`, example:

`$('[data-option-value=".cat3"]').addClass("selected").click()`

Comment: Perhaps you are right. How would I know what this is? Here is an example of the portfolio items:
http://www.enar.ideal-theme.com/wordpress/portfolio/

Comment: @ZackBluem; i don't understand *How would I know what* ***this*** *is?* what happens when u try my code?

Comment: My apologies. When I try your code, its the same outcome as mine. Page loads, correct tab is selected, but it still displays all 10 items from both categories.

Comment: @ZackBluem; I was looking at the markup of that site and it seems my approach *should* work, the class `selected` is only added for styling and informational purposes, it is firing the click event that should show the appropriate categories

Comment: @ZackBluem; can you try this code and tell me what it outputs: `console.log($('.filter_item_block.cat88').children());`? you can place right next to the line in my answer, inside `.ready()`

Comment: The output is very long in the console with many dropdowns to more info. It will not allow me to post all of it here. My category is "3" so i modified that code to cat3 vs cat88. here is part of it: a.fn.init(10)

a.fn.init(10) [div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, div.filter_item_block.cat3, selector: ".filter_item_block.cat3", prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document]

Comment: @ZackBluem; sorry I don't feel like I can do much more from here, I just told you to post that code to rule out the possibility that `$("#filter-by li:first a").addClass("selected").click();` was not working because it might be running BEFORE `$('.filter_item_block.cat88')` was populated, even thought everything is inside `.ready()` it might depend on some other plugin to execute, I really don't know, but try to look into that, try some tests to see if all the `html` is there ready to be manipulated by the time `$("#filter-by li:first a").addClass("selected").click();` runs.good luck

Comment: I found a very similar situation here, that uses a slightly different masonry grid. https://kriesi.at/support/topic/portfolio-only-show-items-from-one-category-by-default/
in my html the item I want to click is `<a data-option-value=".cat3" class="" href="#">` is there a better way with jquery to target the click on the data-option-value=".cat3" here where the class still becomes class="selected"

Answer (score 0):

The class="selected" is enabled once clicked. With that in mind I modified the original attempt. Here was the solution. You definitely helped me figure this out. Thanks!

```
jQuery( window ).load(function() {
  jQuery('#filter-by li:first a').click();
});
```